# How to wait for a set sub-processes to finish

Tags: wait, background-process

I have a master process A.sh and set of sub-processes a1.sh, a2.sh and a3.sh These are executed in this example

```
./A.sh &  // master

./a1.sh &
./a2.sh &
./a3.sh
```

I need to wait till these sub-processes finish before I can start another set of sub-processes say b1.sh, b2.sh, b3.sh in similar manner

```
./A.sh &  // master

./a1.sh &
./a2.sh &
./a3.sh &

// sleep for a1, a2, a3 to finish, then start

./b1.sh &
./b2.sh &
./b3.sh &
```

"wait" commands waits for entire background processes to finish, how do I do it for the set of sub-processes, Do I get wait on basis of every pid of sub-process.